# Using sed to add a string if missing or replace string with wrong value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How in bash with sed can I check if line contains use_authtok.*sha512 and then set or add rounds=5000 ? So far I have only figured out how to add if missing using

```
sed 's/sha512/sha512 rounds=5000/g'
```

in a non-robust way.

example:

```
use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=5
use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=5 rounds=7000
```

desired output:

```
use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=5 rounds=5000     # was missing here
use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=5 rounds=5000     # changed from 7000
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot I'm stumped but so far I was only able to add if missing :  sed  's/sha512/sha512 rounds=5000/g' in a very non-robust way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` too.

```
awk '
/use_authtok.*sha512/ && !sub(/rounds=[0-9]+/,"rounds=5000"){
  $0=$0 " rounds=5000"
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk '(/use_authtok.*sha512/){$5="rounds=5000"}1' file
```

### Output:

```
use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=5 rounds=5000
use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=5 rounds=5000
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this but I wanted to look vaguely for sha512 because it could be almost anywhere in the line, is there a way to wildcard search sha512 ?

Comment: Thanks! I tried googling it with no luck then tried some ugliness where I turned it into a string then into an array to get the field numbers... it wasn't good.

Comment: I don't get what you mean

Comment: Short version, before you had updated your answer I was trying something really ugly. I was going to figure out what column sha512 was in and pass it to awk using arrays and such.